# Drag degradation when SwiftUI macOS [Toolbar -> ToolbarItem -> Button -> Action] contains @State variable reference

Tags: macos, swiftui

**2021/10/28 Update:**
Fixed when building with:

- macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
- Xcode 13.1 (13A1030d)

**2021/10/19 Update:**

- Bug has been submitted to Apple - FB9713387
- Another user has [tweeted about this](https://twitter.com/a_grebenyuk/status/1447724283271258112).

---

Could anyone shed some light on why referencing a `@State` variable inside the following introduces drag degradation/choppiness, or a workaround?

I have tried the following:

- Different variable types
- Using the variable within the `action` and not using it
- Running same code on iOS - no lag at all.
- Xcode Running Xcode Version 13.0 (13A233)

---

##### Code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var iAmAnUnusedBool: Bool = true
    @State private var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            TextEditor(text: .constant("Left Panel"))
            
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 6)
                .onHover { $0 ? NSCursor.resizeLeftRight.push() : NSCursor.pop() }
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .named("contentView"))
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            dragOffset = gesture.translation
                        }
                        .onEnded { gesture in
                            let dragOffsetOriginal = dragOffset.width
                            dragOffset = .zero
                            width = width - dragOffsetOriginal
                        }
                )
            TextEditor(text: .constant("Right panel"))
                .frame(width: width - dragOffset.width)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("Button") {
                    iAmAnUnusedBool // THIS INTRODUCES DEGRADATION
                }
            }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "contentView")
    }
}
```

##### No Lag

Given `iAmAnUnusedBool` is commented out
When I drag the `Rectangle()` back and forth
Then there is no lag
[image: Dragging not laggy]

##### Lag

Given `iAmAnUnusedBool` is uncommented
When I drag the `Rectangle()` back and forth
Then there is lag (appears 1 minute after rapid dragging)
[image: Dragging is laggy]

Comment: Is this for learning goal or in real project issue?

Comment: Real project issue. Do you have a better way of performing the above?

Comment: Did you happen to have a link to the code? The video doesn't seem to explain how it was done.

Comment: Oh I’m not interested in accessing the source code for a payment.

Comment: I have run into this issue too. Apple is apparently aware of it, so hopefully it will be fixed in macOS 12. Until then, or if you want to support macOS 11, I think the only option is to build a native toolbar (i.e. NSToolbar) using AppKit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Adam. Did you happen to have a link where Apple acknowledges being aware of it?

Comment: @Patrick No, unfortunately. An Apple engineer DM’d me on Twitter asking for a Feedback number, which I don’t have, but I pointed him to this post of yours. I’m hoping to put together a Feedback this week; please do the same if you can! :)

Comment: Issue is resolved on latest xcode and macOS @Adam

Comment: @Patrick Glad to hear it! Thanks for following up. Unfortunately I can’t drop support for Big Sur anytime soon, so I’m moving to a native NSToolbar.